# Agregar un orderby a un @Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

estoy trabajando en un formulario creado por entity framework, tengo un dropdown, pero este llama los datos en orden aleatorio

```
@Html.DropDownList("idEmpleado", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Como puedo aplicar un order by ?

Comment: Te refieres a Directamente en el Helper ? porque ahi no se puede, tienes que ordenar la lista de items antes.

Comment: Agrega el controlador y el Action que genera ese HttpGet. Saludos.